# PHP Filter, how to filter input array

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I am using PHP filter to perfom basic sanitization and validation of form data.

The principle problem I am having is that I mark my form up so that all the data is in one array for the POST input. e.g. form fields, page[name], page[slug], page[body], page[status], etc.

Using the following:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'page[name]', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
OR
filter_input(INPUT_POST, "page['name']", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

I am unable to access the variable. Can someone please tell me the correct name to use to access array data using filter_input()

Comment: btw i search like mad on google and turned up nothing.

Comment: Are you sure the variable has a value before sanitizing?

Comment: @anthony yes it does have a value, if i send it through as name it is fine. just not sure of the notation to access an array key using this filter method.

Comment: Not easy at the time, PHP needs to make filter_input_array recursive... For the moment accessing $_POST directly in this case is still much easier.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think that you can access the single value (easily, as you want), however you could just filter the `page` array and get the value that you want.

```
$page = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'page', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
if (array_key_exists('name', $page)) {
    $name = $page['name'];
}
```

Or, if you're OK with losing the ability to work with the raw input then you could just use:

```
if (isset($_POST['page']['name'])) {
    $name = filter_var($_POST['page']['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
```

Both, however, are pretty ugly.

Comment: yeah, both are super ugly. i might as well switch the form to single var names, and avoid the problem. shame that is not supported.

Comment: Absolutely. Single names are much more convenient (for the filter extension) to work with in your case; unfortunately.

Comment: Please check @Fletcher Moore's answer. Very elegant and effective!

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
$_POST['page'] = filter_var_array($_POST['page'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```